# Lambda function capture by copy results in corruped data

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, cocos2d-x

```
std::vector<Spell*> playerSpells{ new Jump(1), new Arrow() };   

for (int i = 0; i < playerSpells.size(); i++)
{
    player->addSpell(playerSpells[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < player->getSpells().size(); i++)
{
    auto spell = player->getSpells()[i];

    player->getSpells()[i]->icon->onClickEndEH.add([=]() {
        auto a = player->getSpells()[i];
        auto b = player->getSpells()[i]->sprite;
    });
}
```

First, I checked`spell` variable and it's fields are initialized correctly. When the lambda function is called, the variable b is corrupted. I can provide other parts of the code if that's not enough.

I simplified it as much as I can;

```
//GAMEOBJECT.H
class GameObject
{
public:
    cocos2d::Sprite* sprite = nullptr;

    GameObject(const std::string fileName = "", bool clickable = false);
    ~GameObject();
};


//GAMEOBJECT.CPP
GameObject::GameObject(const std::string fileName, bool addClickEvent)
{
    if (fileName != "")
    {
        this->sprite = Sprite::create(fileName);
    }
    else
    {
        this->sprite = Sprite::create();
    }

    if (addClickEvent)
    {
        this->addTouchListener();
        this->clickable = true;
    }
}

GameObject::~GameObject()
{
    Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher()->removeEventListener(this->listener);
}

//SPELL.H
class Spell : public GameObject
{
public:
    GameObject* icon = nullptr;

    Spell(const std::string fileName = "", bool clickable = false);
    ~Spell();
}

//SPELL.CPP
Spell::Spell(const std::string fileName, bool clickable) : GameObject(fileName, clickable)
{
}

Spell::~Spell()
{
    delete icon;
}

//ARROW.H
class Arrow : public Spell
{
public:
    Arrow();
    ~Arrow();
};

//ARROW.CPP
Arrow::Arrow() : Spell("arrow.png")
{
    this->icon = new GameObject("arrow.png", true);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps, the spells referred by the pointers in `playerSpells` were destroyed before the lambda was called?

Comment: Either I just suffered a stroke, or this is not valid C++. "for each" and "auto spell in playerSpells" looks like some weird bastard offspring of Python and C++.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I think it's about Visual Studio. I'm going to change it. But it's working.

Comment: @makadev Are you saying this is compliant code? I may be having a stroke too, but this doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: This is Microsoft's C++/CLI, not C++.

Comment: @makadev There is a example using **`for_each`** there is no example using **`for each`** note the space versus the underscore. If you're saying this is legal please provide a better link.

Comment: @user2079303 right.. my fault, comment deleted

Comment: `I can provide other parts of the code if that's not enough.` This is not enough, but don't provide "other parts of the code". Instead provide a [mcve].

Comment: `I checked spell variable before the add function` There is no variable named `spell` in the code you've shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it with adding `retain()` and `release()` functions. I think cocos2dx checks its pool and removes the sprite since it's not being added to the scene in the scope.

```
GameObject::GameObject(const std::string fileName, bool addClickEvent)
{
    if (fileName != "")
    {
        this->sprite = Sprite::create(fileName);
    }
    else
    {
        this->sprite = Sprite::create();
    }

    this->sprite->retain();

    if (addClickEvent)
    {
        this->addTouchListener();
        this->clickable = true;
    }
}

GameObject::~GameObject()
{
    this->sprite->release();
    Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher()->removeEventListener(this->listener);
}
```